# Open url with post param

Tags: javascript

I want to create JavaScript which can make requests with params into Chrome Console.

```
function redirectPost(url, data) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = url;
    for (var name in data) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = name;
        input.value = data[name];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    form.submit();
}
// call on window load
 redirectPost('https://securecode.lisa.mastercard.com/acspage/cap', { PAReq: "eJxdUdFugkAQ/BXjB7AHooJZL7FS0z7QUKtJ7dsVt0paEA8o0q/vnkJt+3DJzmZnbnYWV3tNFDxR&#13;
XGmSGFJRqB31ku20L4YD33X6EqPZko4SP0kXySGTtiUsB6GDzNHxXmWlRBUfb+4fpDPynJGN0EJM&#13;
Sd8H0rHHQgiXmReMmUpJUseOVINwbmF8qLJSN9JzBUIHsNIfcl+WeTEBqOvaorRl5qqx4kMKCGYE&#13;
4eonqkxVsOQp2cowmNX/38Mq/AqDxymCmcCtKkk6wvaFL8Y925m43kQMEc59VKnxIm/Xy4GwBHtr&#13;
G5ibf2YXMOAlEX53kKPVlMWN9MceL9QhpFN+yIgnOJOfGuHqen5nMo1LTsvb+Mf8TdHcjoaLcvG6&#13;
9r36Jd8879Q7m2+HjGLCWfEGF0kDEIwMtEfkdM4X5urP5b8Bv2Ss1A==" });
```

I tried the above code but I get error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Please add more about the error and what you want to accomplish. A Syntaxerror usually means that you've typed something wrong. The error should show a line number where the typo occurs.

Comment: You have to escape new lines in strings. Use a code linter to check for syntax errors. They shouldn't be posted here when tools exist to find them. Try jshint.com for example

Comment: Can you remove end of line in this parameter PAReq: "eJxdUdFugkAQ.....remove this or add " new line +" before new line

Answer (score 0):

You have the string parameter 'PAReq' split across multiple lines, separated with line breaks. That's not allowed. Just set the whole string between the double quotes in a single line.

It looks like inside the base 64 code of the string, you escaped carriage returns, i.e. `\r`, with `&#13;`, but you didn't escape new lines, i.e. `\n`, with `&#10;`. I guess you might need to remove both from the content for it to work as you expect.

The rest of the code looks good to me.